# Get the terms of a custom taxonomy without explicit taxonomy IDs in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I used the following code to try it but it doesnt work. I need all terms of the taxnonmy which are saved for this explicit post. But I only get "array".

```
get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'regisseur', 'Regisseur: <span class="flight">
```

Additional I want to except the ID 43 and 76 – this terms shouldnt be shown in the list.

Why it doesnt work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get all the terms in a post, you should use [wp_get_post_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/)() instead of get_the_terms()

Try this (updated)

```
<?php

$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'regisseur');
if ($terms)
{
    $output = '';
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
    //Here we exclude terms
    if ($term->term_id == 43) continue;
    if ($term->term_id == 76) continue;

            $output .= '<span><a href="' . get_term_link($term->slug, 'regisseur') . '">' . $term->name . '</a></span>';    

    }
};
?>
```

Comment: Ok I tried it but now I have observed a funny thing: Your and my code are working – but the values doesnt exist on the wished place in my content. Instead of that your and my code returns the values on the top of the source code – but still not showing it on the website. The values are only in the source code...I dont know why.

Comment: I use this code inside a plugin template – maybe this information helps you to help me?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of all the code you have

Comment: Hey @orbital I use the Enfold theme and I think this is a general problem. With another solution which I include data via shortcode this values also will be added on the top of the source code...rly strange

the code is massive – its to big i think?

Comment: Screenshot of the function with which you add the shortcode

Comment: Ok, I fixed that other problem with the shortcode. But this problem here is still there. Look at the screenshot of the whole code: https://i.ibb.co/T2zKjf1/Bildschirmfoto-2021-10-20-um-22-37-00.png

Comment: Try updated code